# How to insert foxpro 6 table to visual studio 2017?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-foxpro

Recently I want to renew my old application witch is use foxpro 6 to wrote. Now i want to use VB.net to do a new one. The reason behind is that my project is a POS system for my uncle's shop. since the PC is too old that maybe broken anytime, I need to renew it and compatible with Windows 10 because the new PC is using Windows 10. So that's why I need to make a new app But when i use the link services(data source>add new data source) in Visual Studio, it show my table is blank which is wrong, My table is full of data. so how can i successfully link the table to visual studio?

Connection string `Dsn=inventory`

PS:i use the right odbc driver and test it multiple times and stand still.

Thank You all.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you have VS2017, what motivates using VBA to make a new application? That said I don't think your question can be answered without more specific information.

Comment: sorry that I miss out something, the reason behind is that my project is a POS system for my uncle's shop. since the PC is too old that maybe broken anytime, I need to renew it and compatible with Windows 10 because the new PC is using Windows 10. So that's why I need to make a new app

Comment: sorry I make a big mistake. I'm using VB.net all the time. Sorry for that

Comment: Oh. Ok. Anyway it's nice that you added that backstory, but your post is still lacking the important details that would make it answerable. Are you getting any errors? Is the connection established? You can see the tables but not their data? Visual Studio is just an IDE; do you have actual code that connects to the foxpro data? Can you include a snippet of code that connects and reproduces the problem? See [mcve].

Comment: Well sorry for the blurry.
I search a bunch of website and YouTube videos said that using the function build in the VS can link the tables successfully to the project and go on.
But I tried a couple of  times still can't work.
For example I tried using the data source function to link my table. It shows that the connection is successfully deploy. But when I came to next step of selecting my database object, it shows that my table is empty.
And I tried to create the table on foxpro 9, the VS can recognize and show all the data normally.

Comment: Including your connection string would be a good start

Comment: Actually I thought that's the only method that I can link the table so I tried this only

Comment: `Dsn=inventory`

Comment: may be this is not a connection string?

Comment: Looks like one, but it should be in your post, not buried in comments ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry that I am a noob of programming

Comment: I think you should be able to run a VFP 6 application in Windows 10. Obviously, it would be better to move it up to VFP 9, which definitely runs in Windows 10. But worth testing rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: Since the foxpro 9 is discontinued, I can't use it as commercial use due to the license problem. So I dont prefer using vfp 9 instead of create a new app.

Comment: VFP executables don't require a license for distribution, so the fact that the product is discontinued isn't relevant unless for some reason, your users require a full installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that you can use code instead of wizard to connect the FoxPro table, here's the solution.

Use a connection string to connect the table first, than set a DataAdapter and DataSet for the table, Finally fill the DataAdapter and put it into the DataGridView.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connectionString As String = "provider=vfpoledb.1;data source=your location"
    Dim myConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("FoxPro SQL cmd", myConnection)
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Q")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("Q")
End Sub
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use VFPOLEDB for connection. With VFPOLEDB, you would simply use an OleDbConnection with a connection string like:

```
new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\your data folder")
```

Also check Tom Brother's LinqToVFP, VFP EF Provider and others on codeplex.

IMHO, using windows 10 is not a good reason to rewrite a VFP application in VB.Net. Anyway if you want to do that, then why wouldn't you also change your database backend to something else like postgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, ... etc.

Comment: first thing first, thank you for your answer.
Sorry for the late question, and i would like to ask you a few question about my coding.
i use another method to connect my dbf like:
`Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=vfpoloedb.1;Data Source= mypath\;Collating Sequence=machine"
        Dim dbconnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        dbconnect.Open()
        Application.DoEvents()`
but when i want to use the add new data source wizard, its the same result that i am talking above.Is this method is not suitable for the foxpro table?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use wizards and thus I don't know. I primarily use LinqToVFP (Tom Brothers - codeplex) and direct coding without a dataset (OleDbconnecrtion, OleDbCommand).